# How to read MachineGuid from registry using Inno Setup pascal scripting

Tags: registry, inno-setup, pascalscript

I am trying to read the Machine GUID from the Windows registry using Inno setup pascal scripting function RegQueryStringValue. The registry key I am after is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\MachineGuid

```
procedure StoreHwID();
    var
    HwId: String;

begin
   RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography','MachineGuid', HwId);
   MsgBox('Value is "' + HwId + '"', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

This fails to set a value in the HwId variable.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

InnoSetup is a 32 bit process.  If you are running on a 64 bit OS, you need to specify the 64 bit registry by using `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_64` rather than `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. You might need to have two `RegQueryStringValue` calls.  One for 64 bit and one for 32 bit.

Comment: No need for two calls; the HK** values are just integers, actually. You can just check whether it's 64bit with IsWin64(), store the relevant value in an integer variable, and then use that for the first parameter of your call.