# Inno Setup RegQueryStringValue is not reading values from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Tags: registry, inno-setup, pascalscript

I created a setup to check the product name and the `CurrentMajorVersionNumber` of Windows Server 2019 Datacenter in Inno Setup.

But for any reason I can not get any logs in the Inno Setup file.

I checked the registry location for Server 2019 which is
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`.
The `ProductName` in the registry is `REG_SZ`.
The `CurrentMajorVersionNumber` in the registry is `REG_DWORD`.

```pascal
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  ProductName: string;
  CurrentMajorVersionNumber: string;  
begin
  if RegQueryStringValue(
       HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, '\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion',
       'ProductName', ProductName) then
  begin        
    Log('  > ProductName:' + ProductName)
  end;

  if RegQueryStringValue(
       HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, '\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion',
       'CurrentMajorVersionNumber', CurrentMajorVersionNumber) then
  begin        
    Log('  > CurrentMajorVersionNumber:' + CurrentMajorVersionNumber)
  end;
end;
```

When the above code is ran there is no log available.
Reading other post on this platform regarding this topic could not help me.
Is there any fix?

Answer (score 3):

Inno Setup is 32-bit application. It by default [gets redirected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-redirector) to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node`, when you try to access `HKLM\SOFTWARE` on 64-bit system.

If you want to access the real `HKLM\SOFTWARE` on 64-bit system, use `HMLM64`. You may need to use [`IsWin64`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_iswin64) to choose between `HKLM32` and `HKLM64`, if you need to support both systems.

---

Second thing is that you cannot use `RegQueryStringValue` to read `REG_DWORD` values. You need to use [`RegQueryDWordValue`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_regquerydwordvalue).

Comment: This is virtually the same answer with a bit more details as [this 9 years old one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14739807/4299358) - OP must have encountered it when "_Reading other post on this plattform regarding this topic_"...